# Deploy Ethereum SmartContract on Azure

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, microsoft-azure

I am using truffle to write smart contracts , my code and deployments work well on local ethereum rpc.

Now i added another environment in "truffle.js" file with url to my azure "Ethereum Consortium Leader" rpc .

When I first tried to deploy, i got Locked account error. Then I unlocked my account using provided credentials during setup, using powershell and ssh address also taken from azure deployment.

However now the locked account error goes away.. but my deployment is stuck "Deploying initial_migration.." for few hours now..

Is there anywhere I can find what's wrong? it works perfect locally.

Comment: Not really an Azure answer, but ... are you certain at least one node is mining? What you describe happens on private nets when nothing is mining blocks.

Comment: how do i make sure of it?

Answer (score 1):

*Not specific to Azure.*

In geth, you can

```
> web3.eth.blockNumber
xxxx
>
```

If this number is not rising, no one is mining.

On one of your well-connected nodes, make sure web.3eth.coinbase is set to an account, usually the first account (same one you unlocked), and then

```
miner.start(1)
```

to mine with one thread.

The block number should increase on all nodes as they learn about new blocks.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with azure ethereum consortium leader 2/7/18. I was able to migrate by setting the gas limit under the default. Example truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
    // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
    // to customize your Truffle configuration!
    networks: {
        rpc: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*"
        },
        "live": {
            host: "<ETHEREUM-RPC-ENDPOINT without http:// and port number>",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "1",
            gas: 4612388 // default: 4712388
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't available last year, but now, I found it easy to create a PoA Ethereum network on Azure and deploy a Smart Contract. I recorded it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bisqq7GWRsk).

You fill-in a form with some straightforward information:

[image]

Then you choose regions,

[image]

select number of validator instances:

[image]

and finally you set and admin Ethereum address for PoA:

[image]

There are some advanced options in the same form that one can leave to the defaults.

The deployment takes about 10 minutes. [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/ethereum-poa-deployment) is their official documentation. It's slightly out-of-date.

More specifically, to get your endpoint URL, you have to click to Resource Groups > Deployments > {the last thing in the list} > Outputs:

[image].

Their (self-reported) cost and performance characteristics can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/blockchain/blob/master/ledger/template/ethereum-on-azure/performance-benchmarking/README.md):

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you further elaborate your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged, because the link can go down etc.